# html containing iframe won't display in browser

Tags: html, apache, raspbian

I want to embed a video stream in a html page. I run apache  on a raspberry pi. With the standard index.html it works fine. When I change to my custom index.html, it says the page takes too long to load. This occurs when I access from another network (the internet) not the local network.

This is the content of the html page:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
   <iframe src=”http://192.168.1.56:8081” height=”480”  width=”640”>
   </iframe>
  </body>
</hmtl>
```

My research has led me to X-Frame-Options (this is the best reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options i found).

I have enabled the headers module

```
a2enmod headers.load

systemctl restart apache2
```

and added the following line at the end of the apache2.conf file

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options “ALLOW-FROM http://192.168.1.56:8081”
```

Could you please help?

Thanks!`

Comment: you have said that you are accessing the video from internet, but you are placed here a local network ip range

Comment: I have port forwarding enabled from my public IP to the local IP 192.168.1.56. Could I use another syntax in the iframe, in this case?

Comment: What is running under http://192.168.1.56:8081 this url?

Comment: 192.168.1.56:8081 is the output port for "motion"; this shows a live video stream from a webcam connected to raspberry pi

Comment: The problem is with that Raspberry PI, Check there. First Test the video stream in a local html file on your development machine

Comment: It works in the local network. I tested both on a laptop and on a mobile device. When I try form an external network it doesn't work.

Comment: Then it will be mostly a firewall kind of issue, Check your Htaccess or Firewall